# What are the steps to run phonegap application on Windows7?

Tags: android, cordova

What are the steps required to run Phonegap application on Android system?

Comment: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.6.0/guide_getting-started_windows-phone-7_index.md.html

Comment: StackOverflow isn't a tutorial site, where are you specifically stuck?